# How to publish ClassLibrary as single file in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, publish

Bear with me. It's a bit complicated.

I have a plugin based architecture. The main app implements some cross cutting concerns, and all the business logic is implemented in plugins.
Every plugin is a separate ClassLibrary project (you can think of it as a microservice). Plugin2 can ask main app for a Plugin1 proxy and call it's API.

Main app scans specific directory, takes all the dlls, looks for a marker interface on a class, loads the plugins, and registers them, making them accessible for each other.

I would like to have a plugin as a single file, but I can't. The *PublishSingleFile* property only works for executable applications. At least it's what the error says (*NETSDK1099: Publishing to a single-file is only supported for executable applications*).

So for now I have a whole directory for each plugin with hundreds of files, tens of .dll's...

Maybe I could at least zip each plugin's directory into separate archive during my CI/CD pipeline and then read the assemblies from archive? (I'll be grateful for a sample code)

Maybe you guys have better ideas?

Here is some simplified code. Maybe it will help.

```
// plugin and main app mutual contract nuget
public interface IPlugin
{
    void Start(IApp app);
}

public interface IApp
{
    // used by plugins to get the value from key-value store
    T? GetData<T>(string key); 

    // used by plugins to get a proxy that knows
    // how to communicate with previously published service
    T? GetService<T>(); 

    // used by plugins to make the service accessible for callers
    void Publish<T>();
}


// Plugin1 assembly
public class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    // some service that Plugin1 implements
    private class P1Service : IPlugin1Service
    {
        public P1Service(string connectionString)
        {
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
        }
    }
    
    public void Start(IApp app)
    {
        // get configuration
        var connectionString = app.GetData<string>("itemsDb");

        // initialize service
        var service = new P1Service(connectionString);

        // provide the service for others
        app.Publish<IPlugin1Service>(); 
    }
}

public interface IPlugin1Service // contract nuget
{
    void DoSomething();
}


// Plugin2 assembly
public class Plugin2 : IPlugin
{
    public void Start(IApp app)
    {
        // get Plugin1's service
        var dependency = app.GetService<IPlugin1Service>();

        // use it
        dependency.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a good architecture?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli It brings quite a lot of complexity, but enforces strict boundaries like microservices do, without the overhead of network communication. At any point any plugin can become a separate microservice easily. The question though is about bundling techniques. The architecture part is there for context only.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't understand why the need to make different projects and try to make one dll and persist the COM interface. I would use a folder o zip method. I was thinking about the internal architecture. Your main idea is the foundation of achicture, indeed microservices only copied that.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli quite a lot of the dlls in plugin folders are the same, and that requires extra efforts to manage. Having them all packed in one dll would definitely make the plugin dll unique. Also, working with a bunch of files is more cumbersome than working with just one (per plugin).  
I forgot to mention another nice feature of this achitecture. When you need to scale a service, you just deploy another instance of the main app with that single plugin (service) and it's done.